# Proper Workbench Access/Moderation/Email + Node permissions for my use case?

Tags: 7, nodes, users, workflows, workbench

I've been banging my head against the wall all weekend trying to figure this out but just can't seem to get 100% of the way there... I fix one thing, causing another thing to break. Making me question if the Workbench suite (Access/Moderation/Email) is the right tool for the job.

Roles:

- Auth User: Able to create new Question nodes
- Editor Type A: Able to create + edit Question nodes (tied to Node user permissions) within section Category A (tied to Workbench Access permissions)
- Editor Type B: Able to create + edit Question nodes (tied to Node user permissions) within section Category B (tied to Workbench Access permissions)

Content Type:

1. Question

Category (taxonomy field tied to Question Content Type):

1. A
2. B

Workbench Moderation States:

1. Draft
2. Needs Review
3. Published

Ideal State:

1. Auth Users are able to create a new Question node in Needs Review state; specifying the Category it belongs to
2. Editor A or Editor B is notified via Workbench Email when a new Question node is created and assigned their particular Section
3. Original Author is notified when Editor A/B has moved the Question node from Needs Review to Published

Current State:

1. Auth Users were unable to create new Question nodes until I added the Auth User role to the parent level of the Category taxonomy. Auth Users have permission to create new and view Question nodes, but not edit via Node permissions. Auth Users have a subset of fields attached to the Question content type they are able to create.
2. Because Auth User role is assigned at the parent level, it adds both Editor A and Editor B roles as editors to all categories within the Taxonomy. This causes both Editor A and Editor B to receive email notifications for all categories.
3. Emails are only generated when a user with access to all fields creates the new Question type node. When Auth User users create a Question node, no emails are generated.

Questions:

1. I'm surprised I had to add Auth User role to the parent level Category in order for that role to create new Question content type nodes. I tried practically every combination of user permissions and nothing worked until that (which I don't believe is ideal as it causes Current State #2 to occur). Note: I did use the Workbench Moderation permission checker which stated that the Auth User role should have been a qualified author of new Question content types prior to adding Auth Users to the parent level Category.
2. What would cause the emails to not be generated when an Auth User creates the new Question type?
3. Is there another module I should be considering for what I thought to be a relatively straightforward use case?

Comment: how about using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module together with the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module ? Are you familiar with Group?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not familiar with the Group module, but looks like it could be useful. I worry that setting up all of the different Rules for content state transitions and email notifications would get to be very complex, and potentially out of my skillset. Will research more in the meantime.

Comment: maybe only adding Group for the authorizations part of your question? BTW have a look at the various answers I posted to questions tagged with "group" to get an idea about Group ...